# Getting "invalid cookie state" while trying login with twitter in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, twitter-oauth

I have integrated the Twitter authentication in .NET Core WebAPI project. It redirects to Twitter login page but after that when redirect to "external-login-callback" URL, it is throwing "invalid cookie state"

I have added the AddCookie() and AddSession() but nothing is helping out. I am handling the error page by creating OnRemoteFailure event and redirecting to front end site.

````
           services.AddAuthentication(x =>
           {
               x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           })
               .AddCookie("ExternalCookies", options =>
               {
                   options.Cookie.Name = "external_auth_cookie";
                   options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
               })
               .AddFacebook(option =>
               {
                   option.AppId = Configuration["ExternalLogin:Facebook:AppId"];
                   option.AppSecret = Configuration["ExternalLogin:Facebook:AppSecret"];
               })
               .AddTwitter(options =>
               {
                   options.ConsumerKey = Configuration["ExternalLogin:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
                   options.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["ExternalLogin:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
                   options.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
                   options.CallbackPath = new PathString(Configuration["ExternalLogin:Twitter:CallBackPath"]);
                   options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = ctx =>
                   {
                       ctx.Response.Redirect(Configuration["ExternalLogin:FeCallBackUrl"] + "?err=Login failed");
                       ctx.HandleResponse();
                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                   };
               })
               .AddJwtBearer(x =>
               {
                   x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                   x.SaveToken = true;
                   x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer"),
                       ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Audience"),
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Secret"))),
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidateAudience = false
                   };
               });```
````